# php_pgsql package extension is not loaded automatically from /etc/php.d/ directory

Tags: php, postgresql, redhat, php-pgsql

I have installed php_pgsql package using the command

> yum install rh-php56-php-pgsql.x86_64

I am developing my project with

- PHP 5.6.27
- PostgreSQL 9.6.1
- RedHat 7 OS

instalation was succesful..

> > Installed:   rh-php56-php-pgsql.x86_64 0:5.6.5-9.el7
>
> Dependency Installed:   audit-libs-python.x86_64 0:2.6.5-3.el7
>   checkpolicy.x86_64 0:2.5-4.el7       libcgroup.x86_64 0:0.41-11.el7
>   libsemanage-python.x86_64 0:2.5-4.el7   policycoreutils-python.x86_64
>   0:2.5-8.el7     python-IPy.noarch 0:0.75-6.el7
>   rh-php56-php-common.x86_64 0:5.6.5-9.el7  rh-php56-php-pdo.x86_64
>   0:5.6.5-9.el7   rh-php56-php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.6-3.el7 
>   rh-php56-runtime.x86_64 0:2.0-6.el7  setools-libs.x86_64
>   0:3.3.8-1.1.el7
>
> Complete!

I could find the pgsql.ini file in  /etc/php.d/ directory.
still the php.info page is not showing the pgsql details.

please check my error_log file

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pgsql.so' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pgsql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

So my instalation was not added the pgsql.so file in the right place. I dont know how to sove this issue. please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i solved the issue..

The package instalation was actually done to the DIR PATH

> /usr/lib64/php/modules/pgsql.so

I ensured it with the command

> rpm -ql php-pgsql

from the PHP config file i found the exact **PHP Module** path.
by moving the pgsql.so file into the location made the module enabled for PHP.